# Готовая CMS или ручками?

Tags: php, cms

Какую CMS посоветуете для создания портала? Или лучше написать свою?

Comment: А какие функции у портала должны быть?<img src="/vote/22437/up/" width="1px"/><img src="/vote/20446/up/" width="1px"/><img src="/vote/22354/up/" width="1px"/><img src="/vote/19946/up/" width="1px"/>

Comment: Очень обширные. Если хотите представить нечто похожее по объему но портал министерства фининансов РФ.

Answer (score 4):

Очень абстрактный вопрос. Если множество готовых cmsок, каждая из которых в большей мере заточена под что-то одно ( новости, блоги, форумы и пр...). Определитесь, какие функции должен выполнять ваш сайт, затем посмотрите, какие из них в большем количестве реализованы во всем известных cms, обязательно наличие в cms модульности и расширяемости, чтобы вы смогли дописать (докачать) недостающий функционал из коробки.

Писать cms с нуля я бы не советовал, если вы работаете не в команде. Угробите кучу времени, а получите ту же самую дырявую cms, которую можно скачать в сети.

Answer (score 2):

Какой бы вариант не выбрали, писать самостоятельно или купить готовое решение, или использовать бесплатное решение вы не уйдете от вопроса функционала портала и тут ответ "очень обширные" никак не прокатит, как и сравнение с сайтом минфина.

Правильное решение состоит в понимании структуры портала, его функциональных возможностей и возможностей расширения, если они необходимы.

Далее следует оценить продукты представленные на рынке, насколько они соответствуют требованиям, какова их цена, насколько они удобны в управлении, насколько сложно / дорого довести до ума, если чего то не хватает.

И только после этого принимать решение писать самостоятельон или нет.

Answer (score 2):

я бы посоветовал вам использовать фреймворки.. такие как symfony, zend.. Это мощный инструмент в руках разработчика.

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите наиболее популярную CMS - Drupal, Joomla, ModX. С большой степенью вероятности их функционала, модулей и статей по их изменению хватит для Вашего портала.

Answer (score 1):

Советую взять за основу [drupal](http://www.drupal.ru/), он достаточно гибок для такого рода задачи, и имеет большое комьюнити.

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от от Вашей способности ковырять чужой код, собственно, от Вашего профессионализма. Я не про, потому все пишу сам, сейчас работаю уже над третьей версией своей CMS, ей уже три года)

Comment: если не ПРО, то уж точно не стоит самому писать по-моему :)

Comment: Стоит, хотя бы потому, что в процессе написания идет обучение, плюс ты все в своем коде знаешь и легко можешь добавить/изменить. Я не про, но я не чайник, это разные вещи. А вот изучить, например, на 100% код joomla! - для этого необходимы крайне серьезные знания, потому что подходы у всех разные, таким образом происходит охват огромной области программирования, которую НЕ про просто не потянет.

Comment: Именно для <strong>решения большинства задач</strong>, чтобы не изучать код CMS на 100% есть такое понятие как API. На выходе получаешь работоспособный функционал, при относительно минимальных (по сравнению с собственной разработкой CMS) затратах времени.

Comment: изучение кода известных CMS - тоже обучение и эффективнее чем самому

Comment: >Это зависит от от Вашей способности ковырять чужой код
у меня таких способностей нет, я самоучка, и благополучно делаю сайты практически любой сложности на свой cms. Вначале пытался освоить joomla!, самому писать оказалось легче, и это факт, мой, по крайней мере.

Answer (score -1):

У каждого подхода свои плюсы и минусы.

Если берете готовую цмс то получаете:

- простоту
- удобство
- большинство ошибок поправлены
- имеется сообщество, наверняка есть расширения

Но о ней многие знают, значит:

- У нее есть известные дыры (а под них наверняка эксплоиты)
- Если нет, то их найдут и все равно сломают (исходники то открыты)

Если пишете свою:

- Вы точно знаете, что где надо изменить чтобы добавить цветочек в каждый второй заголовок статьи (т.е. имеете полный контроль над системой)
- Никто не знает как ее сломать
- Вы всегда можете написать модуль для слежения за действиями пользователей на вашем сайте (и например так отлавливать ошибки/взломщиков)

Но:

- Вас никто не застрахует от своих же косяков
- Если их найдут - вам могут не сообщить (а возможно и воспользоваться против вас)
- Это вас также не спасет от взлома не связанного с порталом (например взлом соседнего сайта, для доступа к вашему)

Думаю в целом как то так.

Comment: Только мне кажется что теже, например, Битрикс и Joomla далеки от:
1. простоты
2. удобства
3. исправления большинства ошибок

xD

Answer (score -2):

Конечно лучше написать свою. Моей личной уже год исполняется. Советую фреймворк CodeIgniter. Я например на своей делаю блоги, новостные сайты, сервисы.

Answer (score -2):

Совет!
Попробуй написать сам,скачай фреймворки ,поковыряй,понравится делай свое.

Нет?

Бери архив Joomla,WordPress,Drupal,ModX..........И ковыряй чужой код,форумов куча помогут,создашь конечно не то что хотел но на 80% приближенное.